# Using preg_replace To Change index.php To test

Tags: php

In my forum urls, there is "index.php" in it everywhere. I want to replace it with "test". In my PHP files, I have this line:

```
// Makes it easier to refer to things this way.
    $scripturl = $boardurl . '/index.php';
```

I tried just changing it to:

```
// Makes it easier to refer to things this way.
    $scripturl = $boardurl . '/test';
```

However, that returned 404 errors. I was told that I needed to use preg_replace to make that happen. I looked at the PHP Manual, and it says I need a pattern, replacement, and a subject. I'm confused about the subject part.

I tried this, but no prevail:

```
// Makes it easier to refer to things this way.
    $scripturl = $boardurl . preg_replace('/index.php','/test','?');
```

Here is an example URL: "domain.com/index.php?node=forum"

I want it to look like: "domain.com/test?node=forum"

Comment: Have you tried using `/test/` instead of `/test`? That could be your issue.

Comment: Yes, but still the same problem.

Comment: Wouldn't str_replace be easier for your purpose? http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php Also, have you tried echoing out your created strings to make sure they look how you expect them to?

Comment: I guess if your heart was set on preg_replace you could still use it, but it needs the third parameter (what you want to be searched through for the replacement). In your case: preg_replace('/index.php','/test','ORIGINAL URL').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Like this:

```
$new_url = str_replace('index.php', 'test/', $original_url);
```

Note that [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) would do the job too but it is more complex (and powerful). str_replace() fits in this case.

Just for your info, the subject param for str_replace is the **orginal** string, in your example the url with 'index.php' in it. Your example would look like:

```
$pattern = '/index\.php/';
$replacement = 'test/';
$subject = 'http://yoursite.com/index.php?foo=bar';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

Comment: I am not sure if OP actually wants PHP code to do a find-replace. (Perhaps) he wants to do a find-replace on the PHP code itself.

Comment: If so, he should drop a comment

Comment: I'm all confused about how to achieve my goal. Thanks for the example, it makes sense to me now. Although, I don't think I can use this in my case. I'm told by another that I just change "$scripturl = $boardurl . '/index.php';" to "$scripturl = $boardurl . '/test';" then put something in my htaccess to properly execute anything.